# Get particular content from MySQL dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, content-management-system, pdo

Can someone show me how to get different entries for different requests? Currently the code only shows the first entry no matter what the request is.

PHP

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$host", $username, $password);  
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM data");
try {
    $sth->execute( array($_GET['page']) );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die( $e->getMessage() );
}
list($page) = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
$sth->closeCursor(); 
echo $page;
```

Javascript + jQuery

```
function getPage() {
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
    $.ajax({
        url: "loader2.php", 
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {                  
            $('#content').html(html);
        }
    });
```

The way the code is supposed to work is once an `a href` pointing to say `#home` or `#otherpage` is clicked, the code loads the matching content from my database, by its 'callsign', which matches the link href (e.g. the callsign for `#home` is home). Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be due to the missing of where clause in your select statement?

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE callsign=:page");
try {
    $sth->execute( array(':page' =>$_GET['page']) );
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am inept at php programming... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any bind to any partical column of the table. Please refer the example below:

```
<?php
    $calories = 150;
    $colour = 'red';
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit 
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
    $sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
?>
```

The link below have the details:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the following line is loading one value of the returned array into variable $page:

```
list($page) = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Perhaps try something like this instead, in the last 3 lines of the PHP script:

```
$resultsArray = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$sth->closeCursor();
foreach ($resultsArray as $value)
{
    echo $value."\n";
}
```

This will print all of the results that are returned by the PDO fetch() method.